# I cannot pass arguments to my class in c++

Tags: c++, class

I’m trying to pass an argument to my class but it’s not working

the #includes

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#ifdef _WIN32
#include <Windows.h>
#else
#include <unistd.h>
#endif
```

the class Name and age are vectors Don’t mind the function called oldP

```
    class user{
        public:
        vector<string>Name;
        vector<int>Age;

    
    void outP() {

        for (unsigned int  i = 0; i < Name.size(); i++)
        {

            cout << Name[i] << " , ";

        }
    }
    user(vector<string> name, vector<int> age) {
        Name = name;
        Age = age;
    }

    


};
```

This is the function that uses the name and age and tries to pass it into the class

```
    int holder() {
    string _name;
    int _age;

    int f = 0;



    while (true)
    {
        f++;

        cout << "enter name :";
        cin>>_name;

        cout << endl;

        cout << "enter age :";
        cin >> _age;



        if (f == 6)
        {
            break;

        }

    }

    user user1 = user(_name ,_age);


    
    return 0
}
```

The program partially runs for when the function is called it breaks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your constructor takes arguments of type `vector<string>` and `vector<int>` but you are trying to pass in values of type `string` and `int`.  Since there is no implicit conversion from a given type `T` to a type `vector<T>`, you'll need to rectify that mismatch -- either change the types that constructor accepts, or change the types of the variables that you are passing to the constructor.

Based on the names of the variables, my guess is you want to get rid of `vector` entirely... unless there is some reason why a given `user` should be allowed have multiple names and multiple ages?

Comment: I’m trying to store multiple user data

Comment: In that case, I suggest having each `user` contain just one `string Name;` and one `int Age;`, and declaring a `vector<user> users;` to hold a set of `user` objects, with each `user` object representing exactly one user/person.  (Note that in order to use a `vector<user>` you'll need to declare a default constructor for your user class)

Comment: If you don’t mind giving me a code version of what you just said

Comment: Sorry, you'll have to write your own code, that's how you learn :)

Comment: So I don’t need to use classes